# Cached ram/ Memory leak

Tags: windows, memory, memory-leaks

For the past year or so I have been struggling with 2/3 of ram or more is being cached and not being released to other programs when I need it. Games and browsers crash regularly. I have searched all over the internet for solutions and came to rammap. Idk what to do anymore, I need some answers to what this could be and how I can resolve this. Also I have a ton of service host processes, but three individual antivirus programs show that I have nothing to worry about. Pictures highly related.

[image]

[image]

Additional info

I have a ton of games and heavy work related programs (BIM, PS, VM etc)  but the cached is being made regardless (when I do some light chrome browsing and file management).

Specs:
Msi z170A mobo
gtx 970 
i7 6700K
vengeance LPX DDR4 2x8GB 2600MHz

I might just double the ram as I have two more slots for it, but I don't think that will fix the problem. Possibly just caching more random stuff.

Comment: Why do you have memory compression disabled?  What makes you think memory is not being released, if the memory is cached, Windows would make it aviable to other programs when it was needed.  You have very little of your memory actually in use.

Comment: Because when I open up new programs it crashes. I just tried to edit a photo in PS, but it crashed.
Also I had the system running throughout the night with wifi off. Both browsers just crashed, even though I had 10GB free when I left the computer last night.

Comment: "It crashes" - Can you be more specific?  Your last edit does not address the reason you have memory compression disabled.  Before you make another edit, please refresh the question, as not to lose my improvements to your question.

Comment: Well, photoshop just quit itself, no warning. Firefox says it ran into an unexpected problem and Chome states it is no more memory left.

Comment: I assume you are allowing Windows to handle the size of your page file?

Comment: I am not aparently, I am looking into System properties -> Performance Options -> Virtual memory. It says No paging file. Might this be the culprit?

Comment: So, after your last comment I fiddled around in the Virtual memory paging settings. Set it to system managed size with my SSD as selected drive... BOOM Available is up to 12GB and Cached is at 400MB. 

I cannot believe I haven't looked into this before, thank you Sir/Miss!

Comment: It is very important to differentiate the different kinds of used memory. “Modified” (the more opaque color in Task Manager’s bar chart) is unrelated to “Standby” (==Cached). Though Windows also uses “Modified” memory to enable more efficient disk writes, it doesn’t use this much. Instead, some program is probably using an anonymous memory-mapped file to store temporary data.

Comment: @DanielB Pardon, but Modified is very much related to Standby! Modified pages, after being written to backing store, are moved to the Standby list. With no pagefile, there is no place to write pagefile-backed modified pages, so they just stay on the modified list. The reason one might think the modified list "isn't used much" is that normally the modified page writer threads empty out that list often, so they are usually quite small. But really, _everything_ the pager ever wrote to disk spent time on the modified list, so I woudn't say it's not used much!

Comment: btw, both the Standby and Modified lists are now (Win 8 and later) reported by Task Manager as part of "Cached". Under Windows 7 and earlier the Modified list was not included. Part of Standby, but not all, is repurposed by SuperFetch, and is still counted as "Cached". "Cached" also includes the Windows file cache, which is separate from SuperFetch, and has its own working set even though it's not part of a separate process. And "Standby" (but not Modified) is _also_ counted as part of "Available" (i.e. the opposite of "In Use"), which leads to many "it doesn't add up!" questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a ton of games and heavy work-related programs (BIM, PS, VM etc) but the cached is being made regardless (when I do some light chrome browsing and file management).

It appears you have memory compression disabled, within an Administrator PowerShell command prompt, [`Enable-MMAgent -MemoryCompression`](https://superuser.com/questions/1383484/how-to-enable-memory-compression-windows-10/1383490#1383490) will enable it.  You should also allow Windows, to manage the size of your paging file, based on your comment you don't currently have one.

Comment: The proper course of action would be to upvote my answer and accept it if that is the case.  We try to stay away from comments that just say "thanks"

Comment: Ah, my bad. I have no authority to upvote your answer unfortunately. But your answer is accepted.