# How to keep memory compression enabled after computer restart?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803

I'm currently using Windows 10 1803 LTSB. I've learnt how to enable memory compression but it always revert to disabled after a restart or shutdown cycle. I just want to know if there's a way to keep the setting consistent between restarts.

Comment: Memory compression is ON by default. Are you part of a domain where it is being suppressed by Group Policy? How are you checking if it's enabled? How are you enabling it?

Comment: I am not a part of a domain. I checked if it's enabled through this answer [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1383484/how-to-enable-memory-compression-windows-10) . It was disabled for me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to schedule a recurring task at system startup with admin right to enable memory compression.

[image]

[image]